# How to run npm scripts from global packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

Say, I am making a npm package.

sample package.json:

```
{
   "bin": { "cli": "cli.js" },
   "scripts": { 
    "sample": "node sample.js" 
   } 
}
```

sample cli.js:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell.exec('npm run sample')
```

Then, I run `npm link`

Now, if I run `cli` from anywhere, **other than the project repository**, it does not run. Instead, it throws an error.

I found a workaround by changing cli.js as:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
, package_path = require('./path.json') 
// I manually created this path.json containing the absolute path of the package

shell.exec('npm run --prefix ${package_path} sample')
```

This sort of works. But main limitations are:

- all contributors of the project must manually set this path after cloning the repo.
- if the package is globally installed like `npm i -g package` then this path changing is annoying for the user.

What I'm asking is:

- How can I automate setting the path?
- Any other **better** way to achieve the same behavior, that is,
  calling a `npm script` from a global `cli` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the **elegant** solution to my problems.

Edit the `cli.js` file as:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell.exec(`npm run --prefix ${__dirname} sample`)
```

Node provides some *facade* globals ([read here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html)) which are really helpful.

Here, `__dirname` is the perfect solution. It provides the path of the executing script.

Hope this helps any other developers.